# Why do some Visual Studio projects differ in what is in their Platform dropdown?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, x86, 64-bit

Why do some Visual Studio projects only have "x86" in their Platform dropdown, while others also have "Any CPU" and "x64"?

Comment: did you try to change it, eg x86->Any and build?

Comment: Yes, in two of my projects, the only option is x86.

Comment: Could those projects have been created using Express Edition?

Comment: @Ben - I really doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how it was build my Microsoft for VS 2010. For Visual Studio 2012 they have both the configurations. X86 and x64 and probably they will maintain it that way from here.

For VStudio 2010, you will have to download it manually and install it. There are SP1 and some other installs you might want to take a look in .

Check out [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com). You should be able to find them easily.

Check out this link for step by step instruction: [Steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: I think I'm up to date; my VS 2010 Pro is "Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel"

Comment: Remember, most of the projects in this solution *do* have all three options (x86, x64, Any CPU); only a couple are restricted to x86 only.

Comment: Ok, So did you create a new project? or imported it from an existing one?

Comment: I have had similar issues with 2010 so I had to manually include it later, but in 2012 it was already there.

Comment: This is a legacy solution that I've brought over/down from TFS.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually include it"? What did you manually include, and how?

Comment: After you have installed the package. Go to the dropdown --> Configuration Manager --> In Active Solution Platform dropdown --> <New-->

Comment: All down but 9, pard; set 'em up on the other alley.

Comment: @ClayShannon Am sorry, but I did not get your previous comment.

Comment: I don't know what package you're talking about, or which dropdown.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx Please see the link if it helps.